# Python Panda Concatenate Row and Constant With lamda and Apply()

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, lambda

I can't figure it out...why it won't work for me.

Given that df:

| Product | Final Code | Local Market Code | Import Market Code | Is_import |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Chair | I-^placeholder^-23242 | sistrix | trixsis | 1 |
| Desk | I-^placeholder^-43343 | sistrix | trixsis | 0 |
| Sofa | I-^placeholder^-5454 | gitrix | trixsis | 0 |
| Table | I-^placeholder^-545454 | gitrix | trixgit | 1 |
| Trash Can | I-^placeholder^-545344 | gitrix | trixgit | 0 |
| Rocking Chair | I-^placeholder^-545454 | sistrix | trixgit | 1 |

I need to replace the ^placeholder^ with Import Market Code row and add a "g-" prefix to tha code if Is_import = 1, else Local Market Code.

Without the "g-" constant, it is working great:

```
new_df['Final Code']=new_df.apply(
                  lambda row: 
row['Final Code'].replace('^placeholder^',row['Import Market Code']) if (row['Is_import'] == 1)
else
row['Final Code'].replace('^pubExternalId^',row['Local Market Code'])
            ,axis=1)
```

but when concatenating "g-" constant, it won't add the constant:

```
new_df['Final Code']=new_df.apply(
                  lambda row: 
row['Final Code'].replace('^placeholder^',f"g-{row['Import Market Code']}") if (row['Is_import'] == 1)
else
row['Final Code'].replace('^pubExternalId^',row['Local Market Code'])
            ,axis=1)
```

or in this form:

```
new_df['Final Code']=new_df.apply(
                  lambda row: 
row['Final Code'].replace('^placeholder^',"g-"+row['Import Market Code']) if (row['Is_import'] == 1)
else
row['Final Code'].replace('^pubExternalId^',row['Local Market Code'])
            ,axis=1)
```

Any idea why?

Thanks

Comment: Without getting into the mechanics of pandas, can you replace `'^placeholder^'` with `'g-^placeholder^'` then replace `'^placeholder^'` with `row['Import Market Code']`?

Comment: your code worked on my side. Why are you trying to replace '^pubExternalId^' ? there is no reference of this ? unless this is just a sample ?

Comment: Same for me too, when I changed '^pubExternalId^' to '^placeholder^'.